# Is it possible and correct to say submerge into?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know if it is correct to say:

> we submerge into current affairs such politics, humans rights, economic indicators and...

I am not completely sure if this is possible, and I wish to convey the idea of being immersed in discussion in a productive way.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your question a little bit to explain the context?  Are you talking about a conversation? or is current affairs the person's work?

Comment: ***Into*** doesn't even make it into the top 10 as a preposition after ***submerge***. From NGrams, in descending order of popularity, the most likely prepositions are ***in, by, under, beneath, during, when, to, below, at,...*** But in and of itself, that doesn't make the cited usage "wrong". Opinions may differ on this point, of course - which is why I think there's no real "right answer" here.

Comment: I find nothing wrong with *submerge into* when it is used in a *literal* sense. *I will submerge myself into this tub of water.* But it's seldom used in a *figurative* sense. (I disagree that it has to be *in* rather than *into* in the water example; I think that's just a matter of common usage. And I've heard both. In fact, personally, *into* sounds more natural. But I agree that it's subjective.)

Comment: The verb "submerge" will not take "into", even metaphorically. We can "submerge something in water" - meaning to cover it in water - and we can "put/drop the thing "into" water". But we submerge, or immerse "in water" - not "into". Those two last verbs refer to the position of the item once it has entered the liquid, not the act of getting it in. Hence "into" is inappropriate.

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with the usage you propose.

Comment: @WS2 - So someone could not submerge into a swimming pool??

Comment: @HotLicks The only example I could find in the OED of "submerge into" was of intransitive sense 3a, which is a figurative use - such as submerging into a crowd on the street. The particular example is: *1997   M. J. Shendge Lang. of Harappans 72   When the Asura population abandoned its own ethno-linguistic identity, naturally it submerged into the whole mass.* I'm not saying that "submerge into" is impossible, but it is certainly one I would avoid in any serious piece of writing.

Comment: @WS2  - https://www.google.com/search?q=%22submerge%20into%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1995,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en

Comment: @HotLicks I still don't like it. I certainly accept "merge into", and I think that is how some of these scientific people are using "submerge". "Submerge" is not usually a verb of action anyway, but one of condition.  You don't jump into water and submerge. You jump into water and sink. And after you have sunk, you are submerged.

Comment: @WS2 - So a submarine never submerges?

Comment: @WS2 - https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20submarine%20submerged%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @HotLicks Note that I did say "not usually". When you start talking about technical things like submarines you are into the use of technical jargon. The entry of a submarine into water is a controlled process. One couldn't use "sink", because in terms of naval vessels it has an entirely different meaning. To me "submerge" implies a controlled sinking - which is why we don't usually "submerge into". Before you submerge, you already need to be in the water. I guess that's it.

Comment: @WS2 - "Submerge into", in the OP's example, is being used in a metaphorical sense meaning to completely envelop oneself in the topic.  Saying "merge into" has nothing near the same meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks Well I feel sure there is no law against saying "submerge into", but perhaps no law enforcing its use either. It just doesn't feel idiomatic to me. But perhaps I've led a sheltered life!

Comment: @WS2 - Maybe you've been submerged in a different culture.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't remember submerging into one.

Comment: @WS2 - What does a fish know of water?

Answer (score 1):

the English idiom to **dive in** may be helpful.  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dive)

> To begin or undertake something quickly, enthusiastically, and without
>   trepidation.

Answer (score 0):

You can only submerge *yourself* in something, and it’s ‘in’, not into.

You could say ‘we submerge *ourselves* in current affairs such *as* politics, humans rights, economic indicators and...‘

Although your own word, in your question, immerse, could also be used, and might be better (also with ‘in’).

Etymology:

Submerge is from Latin,  submergere, from sub- ‘under’ + mergere ‘to dip’.

Immerse is also Latin, immers- ‘dipped into’, from the verb immergere, from in- ‘in’ + mergere ‘to dip’.

Usage:

So with **submerge**, you can imply that we are deeply *in* something, like water, with it over our heads. This might be good if you wish to convey that the result is overwhelming.

With **immerse**, you can imply that we have been *dipped into* something - like a corn chip well-soaked in hummous.  This might be good to use if you want to say that we ‘learned a lot’ - as in ‘immersion courses’.  ‘We were immersed in Russian for a week, and learned a lot’.

https://online.prepositionary.com/submerge.htm

(Note - you also need an ‘as’ in your original quote, as I have shown above).

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about a discussion, you could say *we **became engrossed** in current affairs.*  From the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[engrossed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/engrossed)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> *[predicative]* Having all one's attention or interest absorbed by someone or something.
>
> *‘they seemed to be engrossed in conversation’*

You could also phrase it as *we **were engrossed** in current affairs*, depending on context.

Answer (score -1):

You can submerge into a conversation, but you can only get `consumed` by it.

Submerged is placement of you, under water in a topic. But you can be choked, consumed and wet from it.

-

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consumed

: to engage fully : engross

```
consumed with curiosity
```

Same meaning, different way of expressing it

### We submerged ourselves in topics

### and

### got completely consumed with current affairs such as politics, humans rights, economic indicators and..

It feels better to use `consumed` rather then engrossed, but they have the same meaning. so that would be depending on what you prefer i guess.